# SQL Server Management Studio is not available

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

When I installed `SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe` I am not able to connect to my server. The server name is not visible in either image.

Is there any issue in my installation?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to connect remote server or local?

Comment: i am trying to connect local server

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4AkOax_FJ1AWEdKOVFXdXhXTkU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: this is the image. I can not add it in my post

Comment: If you are in Windows Authentication and SqlExpress try dot (.) or like this -> http://i.stack.imgur.com/u9r9V.png

Comment: I believe the SQL Browser service is not turned on by default as a security measure.  You could try turning that on if you really feel you need it.

Comment: then i get this error: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4AkOax_FJ1ANE8tWnROYV9RWkk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @yuck how to turn on it??? can you just give me some suggestions?

Comment: Duplicate of many similar questions? Like this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11629475/microsoft-sql-server-2008-management-studio-connect-server-instance-issue][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11629475/microsoft-sql-server-2008-management-studio-connect-server-instance-issue

Comment: When I installed Express edition I got it. thank you Teoman... Thank you all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First install SQL server 2012 or 2008 R2 on your machine.

[Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062)

[Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 SP2 - Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30438)

Then go to SQL Server Configuration manager and make sure SQL Server Service is running.

[image]

Then user your servername to connect your SQL server in SSMS.

[image]

Comment: HI @TEOMAN I am not able to connect it. bec i have no server. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4AkOax_FJ1ANzBLZ1Vqbjlfb3M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: please check download links on my updated answer.

Comment: i have installed QL server 2012 or 2008 R2

Comment: thank you for your effort. I have installed SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe   so is there need any additional installation???

Comment: Looks like you just installed Management Studio, not services. You need to install them also. Check http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941823 and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549721/no-services-listed-when-sql-server-express-2008-r2-installed-on-local-computer

Comment: When I installed Express edition I got it. thank you Teoman... Thank you all...

Answer (score 2):

to connect to local server and default instance just use any of these `.`, `local`, `localhost` or `YourMachineName`.

If you are trying to connect to a named instance on your local machine just use any of the above followed by `\InstancenName`.

i.e  `.\InstanceName`, `local\InstanceName`, `localhost\InstanceName` or `YourMachineName\InstanceName`.

*Note*

If you want to connect to the default instance you just use the machine name, if you are trying to connect to a Named Instance then you have to use the machine name and the Instance Name.

Comment: all the above are not working. I have tried it earlier.

Comment: @felix go to your services and see if `sql server` is running?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4AkOax_FJ1ANzBLZ1Vqbjlfb3M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I am not able to connect it. bec i have no server.

Comment: Good God it means you have only installed the Client Tools and not the server :) On a side note a suggestion/Piece of Advice if you are installing Sql server so you can practice and learn, Dont install Sql Server Express Edition its pretty basic and crap just spend 50$ and get your self a copy of Developer's Edition.